# Creating a thumbnail image from video by ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, thumbnails

```
$video_name    = $_FILES['video_file']['name'];

$video_tmp_name    = $_FILES['video_file']['tmp_name'];

$video_size    = $_FILES['video_file']['size'];
// where ffmpeg is located  
$ffmpeg = 'C:\\ffmpeg\bin\\ffmepg';  
//video dir  
$video = $video_tmp_name;  
//where to save the image  
$image = 'video/image.jpg';  
//time to take screenshot at  
$interval = 5;  
//screenshot size  
$size = '640x480';  
//ffmpeg command  
echo $cmd = $ffmpeg ."-i". $video ." -an -ss".$interval."  -s ".$size . "-vcodec mjpeg ".$image ." 2>&1";               
shell_exec($cmd);
```

I write down that code. But it's not creating any thumbnail from video. I can't understand what's wrong is with this code.

Comment: It's always urgent... You should include your complete ffmpeg console output so we can see why it may not be producing any output images.

Answer (score 0):

Your code may be quite Linux specific ("2>&!") part.

On Windows I succeeded with this option:

```
 ffmpeg -y -i klip.flv -f mjpeg -ss 10 -vframes 1 160x120 thumb.jpg
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion . i used your code also.but still its not creating .

Comment: Check on the Linux/Vagrant box. PHP on Windows doesn't work well with process execution, unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 0):

this is c# code snippet for video thumbnail.

```
fullVideoPath=@"C:\Users\Madan\Desktop\wpflib\10.wmv"
thumbnailPath=@ "C:\Users\Madan\Desktop\wpflib\Thumbnail\10.jpg"
ffmpeg = new Process();
ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = " -i " + "\"" + fullVideoPath+ "\"" + " -ss 00:00:02 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 200x200 " + "\"" + thumbnailPath+ "\"";                
ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = ffmepgPath;
ffmpeg.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
var status = ffmpeg.Start();
```

Use this It may help you.I have tested it with the following extensions

```
{ ".wmv", ".avi", ".mpg", ".mpeg", ".mp4", ".mkv", ".flv", ".mov", ".vob", ".3gp" }
```